# Adding trailing zeros to specific records in my database

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, find, replace

I created a model that automatically adds a field to a database and concatenates the values in two other fields (block & lot) to create my "pin" field called IDNUM. The problem is that when I download the tax assessment database, I'm losing trailing zeros in both the block and lot fields (ex: 70.10 is 70.1)

Is there a way within the model to analyze the fields before concatenation and add the trailing zeros? I don't have any control over how the tax assessment database is created so I'm looking for a way to streamline this process.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# IDNUM.py
# Created on: 2017-11-28 11:49:18.00000
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Description: 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import arcpy module
import arcpy


# Local variables:
GISDATA = "G:\\ModIV\\GISdata.mdb\\GISDATA"
GISDATA2 = GISDATA
GISDATA3 = GISDATA2

# Process: Add Field
arcpy.AddField_management(GISDATA, "IDNUM", "TEXT", "", "", "", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")

# Process: Calculate Field
arcpy.CalculateField_management(GISDATA2, "IDNUM", "[Block] & \"-\" & [Lot]", "VB", "")
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! What is your question?  What are you trying to do, what happens when you run your code?  Please include any error messages.  You can [edit] your question to include additional information.

Comment: If you can create a new field/define the field type before hand as  "text" or "string" it should retain the zeros.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python ljust() function to left justify text and fill with what ever characters, in your case a zero.

The python expression would be:

```
str(!Block! ).ljust(5,"0") + "-" + str( !Lot!).ljust(5,"0")
```

so if block was `70.10` and Lot was `28.10` this would create `70.10-28.10`